# Formatting percentage using Inputmask

Tags: javascript, jquery, percentage

I'm using Herbots' InputMask, and it works well but I notice that it handles percentages such that a value of 0.4 with a mask of "0.00%" is formatted as "0.4%".

Well, sure. Makes sense. Except I'm dealing with the actual percentage value, which is a value between 0 and 1, so that 0.4 should show up as "40.00%" with said mask.

I've run into this problem before (with other masking systems) and tried to fix it at the form level by multiplying the incoming value by 100 and dividing it on the way out, but that's an ugly thing. Is there something in InputMask (a preprocessor or custom hook) that would allow me to format the real value as a proper percentage?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the way I worked around this was using the onBeforeMask and onUnMask functions. In Clojure, it was:

```
:onBeforeMask (fn [value opts] (str (* 100 (cljs.reader/read-string value))))
:onUnMask (fn [maskedvalue unmaskedvalue] (str (/ unmaskedvalue 100)))
```

I'll still credit an alternative to massaging the data, if there is one. The key seems to be that onBeforeMask gives you a string and expects a string back, where onUnMask will give you a number (but still expects a string back).